# use django message framework to show if user already voted

Tags: python, django

I need to check and display with django messages framework if user is already voted, then display in results page, that you have already voted, but if he isnt then show Your vote has been saved. So I added the sucess message, but rly dont know how to check if user has voted.

my models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __uncidoe__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

my views.py

```
def results(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id) 
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your vote has been saved !!!')
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'poll': poll})
```

my results.html

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
{% for message in messages %}
<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{message.tags}}" {% endif %}>{{message}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{%endif%}
```

**EDIT:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

my vote def

```
def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new model to store Vote for each User. Dummy solution:

```
class UserVote(models.Model):
    pool = models.ForeignKey(Pool)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('pool', 'user')
```

and view handling user's choice submission:

```
def send_result(request, poll_id, choice_id):

    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)

    vote, created = UserVote.objects.get_or_create(pool=pool, user=request.user, defaults={'choice': choice_id})
    if created:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your vote has been saved !!!')
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Your already voted before !!!')
    return redirect(reverse('results', pool=pool_id))
```

a view displaying the voting form:

```
def vote_form(request, pool_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    choices = Choice.objects.filter(pool=pool)
    return render(request, 'vote_form.html', {'choices': choices, 'pool': pool})
```

and its template:

```
<form action="{% url 'send_result' pool_id=pool.id %}">
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice_id" value="{{ choice.id }}"> {{ choice.choice_text }}<br />
        <input type="submit" value="vote">
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: I get this error, that it takes exactly 3 arguments(2given) ?

Comment: well... you didn't specify which function or which line raises this exception so I'm not able to help you

Comment: in views.py def function, you give 3 arguments, but 2 are defined, i guess it doesnt like `choice_id`

Comment: Indeed - you have to pass the user submitted choice to the view. I dont know how does your form and urls.py look like so it's up to you to pass it from there. When it's done, can use this to check if user has already voted or not.

Comment: ok, i added urls and my vote def, can u help me out with that? I am kind a new to django.

Comment: I added a view + a template for displaying the voting form.